# MVVM - Behavior with Parameters or Find Specific Parent/UserControl Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So, I am fairly new to MVVM and have backed myself into an interesting corner where I am not sure how to make things work with either a behavior or a command. I have a user control that contains a listbox of items which need to implement various behaviors such as deleting or removing the given item. Like so:

```
<UserControl> // DataContext is a viewmodel
    // Borders, grids, various nesting controls...
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Items" ItemSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate> // From here on the individual item has its own data context of type Item in ItemsList
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="EditItemStuffOnLoseFocus" Text="{Binding ItemStuff}"/>
                    <Button Name="DeleteItemStuff"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

The example has been simplified, but the basic idea is that the textbox should edit its associated  listbox item when it loses focus and the button should delete the associated listbox item when pressed. At first I implemented commands for this and had both working, until I realized that I had forgotten the standard "Are you sure?" message. I added this in the command, but since it has no concept of the actual objects, I can't think of how to tell it where to put the dialog window. The command accepts a view model (_ViewModel) on creation and accepts the Item model (textbox/button's DataContext) as a parameter. With the basic message box dialog, the Execute() method looked something like this (simplified):

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Really delete the item?", "Delete Item", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        ItemService service = new ItemService();
        service.RemoveItem(((Item)parameter).ItemID);

        if (_ViewModel.ReloadItemListCommand.CanExecute(_ViewModel.ItemInfo))
            _ViewModel.ReloadItemListCommand(_ViewModel.ItemInfo);
    }
}
```

Of course, this message box is not centered on the application, which is small but annoying. A coworker suggested that I replace the Command with a Behavior so that I would have an associated object to use for centering the message box. The problem is, I haven't been able to find any information on passing parameters to a behavior, or how to trace back multiple levels from an associated object to its parents so that I can get the view model for the reloading step as well as the individual item's model (the associated object's DataContext).

In summary, is there a way to either center the MessageBox on the application within the command while remaining MVVM-friendly, OR to pass parameters / retrieve a specific parent object or its resources using a behavior?

____________ UPDATE ____________

The answer below works great, but I went another route so that I could use DataContext variables in my MessageBox. I managed to preserve access to the DataContext of the calling control and the view model by adding the view model to the control's tag:

```
<UserControl> // DataContext is a viewmodel
    // Borders, grids, various nesting controls...
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Items" ItemSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate> // From here on the individual item has its own data context of type Item in ItemsList
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="EditItemStuffOnLoseFocus" Text="{Binding ItemStuff}" Tag={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                    <Button Name="DeleteItemStuff" Tag={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

I'm not entirely certain this is the best way to be using Tag, but it does get all the information I need into the behavior while allowing me to center the MessageBox. The behavior is similar to the command except for a few added lines to extract the model and view model. Keeping with the initial shortened example, it looks something like this:

```
ExampleViewModel viewModel = (ExampleViewModel)AssociatedObject.Tag;
Item parameter = (Item)AssociatedObject.DataContext;

if (MessageBox.Show(Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject), "Really delete the item?", "Delete Item", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        ItemService service = new ItemService();
        service.RemoveItem(((Item)parameter).ItemID);

        if (viewModel.ReloadItemListCommand.CanExecute(viewModel.ItemInfo))
            viewModel.ReloadItemListCommand(viewModel.ItemInfo);
    }
}
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is overkill for your solution, but I've always used a custom UserControl for any kind of Popup in my WPF application. The code I used is posted [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) if you are interested in attempting this approach, or I could write this up as a full answer with more detail on how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center a message box on a window will require you to either implement your own Window and do a ShowDialog where you can specify the location. Or you can inherit from the Forms control done in this [CodeProject Solultion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59483/How-to-make-MessageBoxes-center-on-their-parent-fo).

However for the first part of your problem It would most likely be easier to implement a click handler on the button and bind the delete to your user control as a dependency property. This would allow you to have access to the sender and keep the UI compeltely inside the control.

xaml

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Button Click="Button_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Code Behind

```
public ICommand DeleteItem
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteItemProperty, value); }
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DeleteItem", typeof(ICommand), typeof(control), new PropertyMetadata(null));
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeleteItem != null)
        {
            var result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("WOULD YOU LIKE TO DELETE?", "Delete", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
                if (DeleteItem.CanExecute(fe.DataContext))
                {
                    DeleteItem.Execute(fe.DataContext);
                }
            }
        }
```

Just have your delete command bind from the outside and do the logic for your message box in the click event.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I see how the solution uses FrameworkElement to pass the button's DataContext without breaking MVVM, but I am still hoping for something that doesn't rely on the code behind (mostly because I would really like to show some of the DataContext information in the message box message without making the code behind tie in too much with the model being used). I will wait a bit longer and check out the code project solution as well.

Comment: I think you are correct, however the paradigm is that view does know how some information about the viewmodel. This is why we statically state the binding. If you want to keep the information as loosely coupled as possible I would suggest having the ViewModel inherit from and interface that would give the data in a string. Another alternative is you can have an attached property that has a binding to the string you wish to pass, You could then fetch that attach property in the code behind. I am not sure if you are going to get away from the code behind.

Comment: Ultimately wound up going another route to preserve viewModel access, but going to mark this as the answer because it works for the question as it was posted. I'll also update my question to give the workaround I used in case it helps others.